# How to write this sum $\sum_{m=0}^\infty (2m+1)^{-2k-1} \sum_{r=1}^\infty (-1)^{r-1} e^{-2(2m+1)r a} $ as a sum over single index?

Tags: summation, divisor-sum, summation-method

So I want to write the sum $$\sum_{m=0}^\infty (2m+1)^{-2k-1} \sum_{r=1}^\infty (-1)^{r-1} e^{-2(2m+1)r a} $$  where $a>0$ and $k\in \mathbb{N}$, as a sum over single index which probably uses odd divisors of $(2m+1)\cdot r$.

However, I am quite confused about this method in general. I am trying to learn this concept. If anyone can help me with the logic, it will be highly appreciated.

Comment: What is $k$ - a variable? an integer?

Comment: @unseen_rider $k \in \mathbb{N}$, I have added this in question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let
$$ S := \sum_{m=0}^\infty (2m+1)^{-2k-1} \sum_{r=1}^\infty (-1)^{r-1} e^{-2(2m+1)r a}. $$
Then, as you suggested using odd divisors, get
$$ S = \sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n-1} e^{-2\,n\,a}\left(
\sum_{d|n,\,d\text{ odd}} d^{-2k-1}  \right) $$
where $\,d=2m+1\,$ and $\,n=(2m+1)r.$

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if you're supposed to do this some specific way. I would just utilize the fact that the inner sum is a geometric series. You can easily get
$$\sum\limits_{r=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{r-1}e^{-2(2m+1)ra} = -\sum\limits_{r=1}^{\infty}\left(-e^{-2(2m+1)a}\right)^{r} = \begin{cases}\frac{e^{-2(2m+1)a}}{1+e^{-2(2m+1)a}} & a > 0\\ \infty & \text{otherwise}\end{cases}.$$
This can be rewritten as
$$\sum\limits_{r=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{r-1}e^{-2(2m+1)ra} = \begin{cases}\frac{1}{1+e^{2(2m+1)a}} & a > 0\\ \infty & \text{otherwise}\end{cases}.$$
I don't know if this helps. I hope it does!

Comment: No, I specifically want to reduce the summation index over divisors or something like that. The actual term was what you have obtained. I rewritten it in the form of double sum, now I want to get it as single sum over index of earlier stated form.

Comment: @Kashif you could then use Davis's final closed form result, and substitute in for the inner sum. Then you have one summation in one index for $a>0$ and infinity otherwise

Comment: @unseen_rider can you please explain in a new answer?